# Получение ближайших символов в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
Добрый день! 5 = V  D = X
```

Мне нужно получить комбинации `5 = V` и `D = X`.

Comment: И как вы определяете, что нужно получить именно эту часть текста?

Comment: В этом то и есть проблема. Мне нужно найти подстроку где один символ = другому символу не имея при этом ни того символа, ни другого.

Comment: `.[ \t]?=[ \t]?.` один символ = другому символу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
a = "Добрый день! 5 = V D = X"
params = re.findall(r"(\w+\s*?=\s*?\w+)\s*?", a)
print(params)
```

> ['5 = V', 'D = X']

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вероятней всего эти параметры нужно будет как-то использовать, немного допилил предыдущий ответ:

```py
import re

a = "Добрый день! 5 = V D = X"
params = re.findall(r"\w+\s*?=\s*?\w+", a)
p_dict = {k: v for param in params for k, v in [re.split(r'\s*=\s*', param)]}
print(p_dict)
# {'5': 'V', 'D': 'X'}
print(p_dict['5'])
# V
print(p_dict['D'])
# X
```

Comment: Ваш код можно упростить используя группы в регулярных выражениях: 
```params = re.findall(r"(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)", a)
p_dict = {k:v for k, v in params}```

Comment: @ReinRaus да чето я ступил. Спасибо